When does the Strong Markov Property not apply?
I am having a lot of trouble understanding the Strong Markov Property.
I think I understand the regular Markov Property.

Regular Markov Property: For some Discrete Time Markov Chain, the state at time=n+1 only depends at time=n. I think this is obvious because this is how we define the Markov Chain (by definition):

$$P(X_{n+1} = j | X_0 = i_0, X_1 = i_1, ..., X_n = i_n) = P(X_{n+1} = j | X_n = i_n)$$
To me, this is like saying: Suppose I make an ice cream sundae and put a cherry on top. I put it in the freezer and come back one day later. Assuming nothing happened during that time, there will still be a cherry on top of the ice cream sundae because I placed it there to begin with. Thus, in a Markov Chain, the regular Markov Property should always hold because I construct the Markov Chain and transition matrix such that the probability of being in any state can only be influence by which state I was in previously. It seems like all Stochastic Processes should obey the Regular Markov Property.
Now, for the Strong Markov Property. Here is my attempt to summarize it:

Strong Markov Property: Given a (random variable) stopping time $\tau_k$ (e.g. the first time the process enters state $k$), the Strong Markov Property can be expressed as:

$$
P(X_{\tau_k + t} = j | X_0 = i_0, X_1 = i_1, ..., X_{\tau_k} = k) = P(X_{\tau_k + t} = j | X_{\tau_k} = k)
$$
To me, this means that the occurrence of the first (random) stopping time does not affect the Markov Chain.

I tried to think of an example to see the Strong Markov Property in action.

Suppose there is a 5 State Markov Chain:
$$
P_{i,j} = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} & p_{14} & p_{15} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23} & p_{24} & p_{25} \\
p_{31} & p_{32} & p_{33} & p_{34} & p_{35} \\
p_{41} & p_{42} & p_{43} & p_{44} & p_{45} \\
p_{51} & p_{52} & p_{53} & p_{54} & p_{55} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I define the Stopping Time $\tau$ as each time the Markov Chain enters State 5.
Suppose I say that at time=0, the initial distribution of being in any state is given by (i.e. there is 0 probability of being in state 5 at time=0):
$$\pi^{(0)} = (p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, 0)$$
$$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 = 1$$
The probability distribution of being in any state at time $t=\tau+1$ given the initial distribution at time $t=0$ can be obtained by multiplying the initial distribution by the transition matrix $P$ raised to the power $\tau+1$:
$$P(X_{\tau+t} = i \mid \pi(0))  = \pi^{(0)} P^{\tau+t}$$
On the other hand, if the Markov chain is in state 5 at time $t=\tau$, then the probability distribution of being in any state at time $t=\tau+t$ is given by (given by the 5th row of the transition matrix) :
$$P(X_{T+t} = i | X_T = 5)  = (0,0,0,0,1) \cdot P^{T +t -\tau} = (0,0,0,0,1) \cdot P^{t} = p_{5,i}^{(t)} $$
Thus, it appears that:
$$P(X_{\tau+t} = i \mid \pi(0))  = P(X_{T+ \tau} = i | X_T = 5)$$
By virtue of the Strong Markov Property, the probability of going from any state at time=0 to any state at time= $\tau$+t is equal to the probability of going from state=5 at time= $\tau$ to any state at time= $\tau$+t.

Did I understand the Strong Markov Property correctly? To me this seems somewhat obvious since the next position of a  Markov Chain is designed to only depend on the current position of a Markov Chain - regardless if the current position is a deterministic time (i.e. regular Markov Property) or a random Stopping Time (i.e. strong Markov Property.). At each step, the Markov Chain naturally resets and equations like Chapman-Kolmogorov can be used to recursively determine the probability of the Markov Chain being in any given state given the distribution of state occupancy at any previous time.

Furthermore, it seems like almost all Stochastic Processes should obey the Strong Markov Property. I would really have to go out of my way to significantly "alter" a Stochastic Process for it to not follow the Strong Markov Property. For example, create a Stochastic Process such that the Stopping Time is defined when the Process enters an Absorbing State and thereby terminates permanently.... or an example where after the Process experiences its first Stopping Time, the properties of the Process are changed (e.g. transition probabilities are modified). Are there any examples where a Stochastic Process does not follow the Strong Markov Property?



In short: any discrete Markov chain has the strong Markov property.
